# How can you configure magit for duet-commit?

Tags: magit

The following code used to work with earlier versions of emacs, adding a ‘d’ option to [magit](https://magit.vc)'s commit popup for ‘[git duet](https://github.com/git-duet/git-duet)’.

```lisp
(require 'dash)

(defvar magit-duet--default-commit-popup-actions nil
  "Store the magit-commit-popup here for
     de-initializing. magit-duet-commit")

(defun magit-duet-commit (&optional args)
  "Create a new duet commit"
  (interactive (if current-prefix-arg
                   (list (cons "--amend" (magit-commit-arguments)))
                 (list (magit-commit-arguments))))
  (when (setq args (magit-commit-assert args))
    (magit-run-git-with-editor "duet-commit" args)))

(defun magit-duet-commit-init ()
  "Add duet-commit to magit commit popup.."
  (interactive)
  (when (eq magit-duet--default-commit-popup-actions nil)
    (setq magit-duet--default-commit-popup-actions
          (plist-get magit-commit-popup :actions))
    (plist-put
     magit-commit-popup
     :actions
     (-remove-at 5 (-insert-at 4
                               '(100 "Duet commit" magit-duet-commit)
                               (plist-get magit-commit-popup :actions))))))

(defun magit-duet-commit-deinit ()
  "Remove duet-commit from magit commit popup.."
  (interactive)
  (unless (eq magit-duet--default-commit-popup-actions nil)
    (plist-put magit-commit-popup
               :actions
               magit-duet--default-commit-popup-actions)))
```

Credit to jasonm23: https://gist.github.com/jasonm23/6326d278d99fe82f252a90d9b9ad61db

This no longer works with more recent versions of emacs.

How might this snippet be fixed for the latest emacs?
Similarly what would be the best solution for [git duet](https://github.com/git-duet/git-duet)’s integration with magit overall?

---

### Update

As per @tarsius suggestion, the following works perfectly:

```lisp
(require 'dash)
(require 'magit)

(defvar magit-duet--default-commit-popup-actions nil
  "Store the magit-commit-popup here for
 de-initializing. magit-duet-commit")

(defun magit-duet-commit (&optional args)
  "Create a new duet commit"
  (interactive (if current-prefix-arg
                   (list (cons "--amend" (magit-commit-arguments)))
                 (list (magit-commit-arguments))))
  (when (setq args (magit-commit-assert args))
    (magit-run-git-with-editor "duet-commit" args)))

(defun magit-duet-commit-init ()
  "Add duet-commit to magit commit popup.."
  (interactive)
  (when (eq magit-duet--default-commit-popup-actions nil)
    (transient-append-suffix 'magit-commit "c"
      '("d" "Duet commit" magit-duet-commit))))

(add-hook 'magit-mode-hook 'magit-duet-commit-init)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual command `magit-duet-commit` should still work. It looks like it was created by copying `magit-commit-create` and then making some minor changes. That upstream command was changed slightly since it was originally copied and modified, so the copy should be updated too:

```
 (defun magit-duet-commit (&optional args)
-  "Create a new duet commit"
+  "Create a new commit on `HEAD' attributed to two authors.
+With a prefix argument, amend to the commit at `HEAD' instead.
+\n(git commit [--amend] ARGS)"
   (interactive (if current-prefix-arg
                    (list (cons "--amend" (magit-commit-arguments)))
                  (list (magit-commit-arguments))))
+  (if (member "--all" args)
+      (setq this-command 'magit-commit-all)
+    (setq this-command 'magit-commit-create))
   (when (setq args (magit-commit-assert args))
-    (magit-run-git-with-editor "duet-commit" args)))
+    (let ((default-directory (magit-toplevel)))
+      (magit-run-git-with-editor "duet-commit" args))))
```

The rest of the code was not even the proper way of doing this when it was created. Back then the `magit-popup` library was used to create these "transient prefix popups". Now the `transient` library is used instead.

Transient's manual [documents](https://magit.vc/manual/transient/Modifying-Existing-Transients.html) how new commands can be added to an existing transient prefix. In this case:

```
(transient-append-suffix 'magit-commit "c"
  '("d" "Duet commit" magit-duet-commit))
```

Comment: that’s fantastic. Thanks!